# Issue converting stringBuilder + forloop to stream + map

Tags: java, java-stream, stringbuilder

- What I am trying to achieve:

I would like to convert a StringBuilder + forloop, like this:

```
public String question(List<MyPojo> myPojos) {
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (MyPojo myPojo : myPojos) {
        try {
            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myPojo);
            stringBuilder.append(json).append("\n");
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                LOGGER.warn("bad");
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Into a stream() structure. This is not for performance, readability, or anything, I just want to try the conversion.

- What did I try:

```
public String question(List<MyPojo> myPojos) {
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    return myPojos.stream().map(onePojo -> delegate(onePojo, stringBuilder)).toString();
}

public StringBuilder delegate(MyPojo oneMyPojo, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    try {
        var json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oneMyPojo);
         stringBuilder.append(json).append("\n");
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                LOGGER.warn("bad");
    }
    return stringBuilder;
}
```

- Issue

Unfortunately, the result string is not at all the same as the one provided by the for loop.

- Question

What did I miss in my code?

Comment: Can you gives as an input/output example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a StringBuilder at all in your example, you can simply use `.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))` to join your strings, your can can be like this:

```
public String question(List<MyPojo> myPojos) {
    return myPojos.stream()
        .map(this::convertToJson) // Convert the object to json string
        .filter(json -> json != null && !json.isEmpty()) // retrieve non null or empty jsons
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")); // combine the result with backline separator
}

private String convertToJson(MyPojo myPojo) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myPojo);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("bad");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, calling `Stream.toString` will not give you anything meaningful. It is very unlikely that the `Stream` implementation actually overrides `toString` to give you the elements of the stream all concatenated as strings. You should use `.collectCollectors.joining("\n"))` to join everything together.

Second, the function you passed to `map` modifies the existing `stringBuilder`. While you will probably get the expected result in `stringBuilder` if the whole stream is consumed, this is not how `map` is designed to be used. You are supposed to return the element that a given element should be transformed into, but the `StringBuilder` you are returning here contains all the results from the previous elements.

Third, the loop does not append anything to the string builder when an exception occurs, but `Stream.map` transforms every element. To implement this behaviour, you would need `delegate` to return a special value (like an empty string), and `filter` out that value after `map`. Alternatively, use `flatMap(x -> delegate(x).stream())`, where `delegate` returns an `Optional<String>`.

```
public String delegate(MyPojo oneMyPojo) {
    try {
        var json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oneMyPojo);
        return json;
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("bad");
    }
    return "";
}

// ...

myPojos.stream()
    .map(onePojo -> delegate(onePojo)) // you can also use a method reference here
    .filter(json -> !json.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

or

```
public Optional<String> delegate(MyPojo oneMyPojo) {
    try {
        var json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oneMyPojo);
        return Optional.of(json);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("bad");
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

// ...

myPojos.stream()
    .flatMap(onePojo -> delegate(onePojo).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```